# Singularity or stiff system in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have the following piece of code

```
(*UV cuttoff*)
rmax = 10;
(*Fixed input values*)
nc = 4;
nf = 4;
(*Value of α1*)
α1 = 0.95;

b0 = 1/(6 π) (11 nc - 2 (nc + 2) nf) ;

b1 =  1/(24 π^2) (34 nc^2 - 10 nc (nc - 2) nf  -  
     6 (nc + 1) (nc - 2) (nc - 2) nf) ;

eqalp1 = alp1'[mu1] + (b0 alp1[mu1]^2 + b1 alp1[mu1]^3) == 0;


sol1 = NDSolve [{ eqalp1, alp1[0] == α1}, 
   alp1, {mu1, 0, 10^24}];

alph1[mu1_] := First[Evaluate[alp1[mu1] /. sol1]]

alph1[mu1];
α[mu_] := alph1[mu]
```

It works fine if I choose `nf=1,2,3` but when I set `nf=4` and higher I get the following error message

[image: error]

I tried to solve the differential equation not from zero but from other points. Every time I get a similar error. I also tried changing the tuned input for `α1` in the beginning of the code, but the same message persists.

Can someone suggest something to bypass this?

P.S: I have used different combinations of max steps and working precision.I forgot to mention that previously. Finally, I tried to adopt  [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117761/ndsolve-error-step-size-is-effectively-zero-singularity-or-stiff-system-is-sus) and use the `WhenEvent` command but it has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ODE can be solved exactly, by the way.  The time to reach a singularity is given by the following integral, if it converges:

```
Integrate[
 -1/(b0 alp1[mu1]^2 + b1 alp1[mu1]^3), 
 {alp1[mu1], α1, Infinity}]

(*  0.451388  *)
```

Therefore the IVP has a singularity around `mu1 = 0.451`. This agrees with the numerical integration performed by `NDSolve` (for `nf = 4`).

(The integral comes from separating the variables.  Given
$${d\alpha\over d\mu} = v(\alpha)\,,$$
we get, starting from the initial condition $\alpha(0)=\alpha_1$,
$$\int_{\alpha_1}^{\infty} {d\alpha \over v(\alpha)} = \int_0^M d\mu = M$$
The value of $M$, if the integral on the left converges, is the time $\mu = M$ at which $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need the numerical interpolation for practical reasons thought as I have to use it as input for other equations.

Comment: @A_user_with_NoName You're welcome.  I guess I was thinking you could use the exact solution to verify the results returned by `NDSolve`.

Comment: this makes sense, of course. I guess that since I missed something so obvious it is a good time to stop for today and start fresh tomorrow. Thanks again for your reply!